# std::isnormal in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point

Is this correct? Is this portable to .NET core and 32-bit ARM Linux? Is there a faster way, maybe something in the .NET framework? Is there a way to implement float32 version without using dynamic memory i.e. without byte arrays?

```
/// <summary>Determines if the given floating point number is normal, i.e. is neither zero, subnormal, infinite, nor NaN.</summary>
public static bool isNormal( this double v )
{
    long i64 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits( v );
    long expMask = 0x7ff0000000000000L;
    long expBits = i64 & expMask;
    return expBits != 0 && expBits != expMask;
}

/// <summary>Determines if the given floating point number is normal, i.e. is neither zero, subnormal, infinite, nor NaN.</summary>
public static bool isNormal( this float v )
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes( v );
    uint i32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32( bytes, 0 );
    uint expMask = 0x7f800000;
    uint expBits = i32 & expMask;
    return expBits != 0 && expBits != expMask;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code is formally correct, just change the name to `IsNormal()` (PascalCase) to follow *standard* .NET naming conventions.

However your second question *"Is this portable to .NET core and 32-bit ARM Linux..."* is little bit more tricky. In normal conditions you should almost never care about host endianness but floating point numbers have exceptions on ARM (and possibly some other architectures which, however, don't run .NET Core). Specifically:

- ARM EABI does not store floating point numbers using the *natural-endianness* but a mixed-endian convention. You can't compare `BitConverter.GetBytes(v)` result with an `int` because they're surely encoded differently.
- CirrusLogic Maverick (formally EP9312) is an ARM9 System-on-chip with a MaverickCrunch math cooprocessor where floating point numbers are always little-endian. You can't compare `BitConverter.GetBytes(v)` result with an `int` because they may be encoded differently.

Honestly, regardless the CPU, I am not sure about Linux images compiled with software floating point support then (if you need to support them) you have to try (or find related documentation).

The good news is that you probably won't ever need to deal with them. The bad news is that, if you really need to, compiling for `AnyCPU` you have to detect
endianness at run-time (and ARM CPUs may be configured...)

Comment: About the names, I’m not doing that. It’s easier to read the code when I can distinguish my extension methods from .NET framework’s methods, extension or not, by just looking at their names.
Thanks for the comment about ARM. So far, I’m only supporting Rockchip’s RK3288 CPU running Debian kernel.

Comment: @Soonts I can't really agree but it's really a minor point. RK3288, unless you're using an image compiled with _soft_ floating point support (in that case...I'm not sure), should work as expected.

Comment: @Soonts _About the names, I’m not doing that._ - you are, as soon as you're not working alone but with a team that follows the conventions :-P

Comment: @t3chb0t Unless I’m the team lead. I think naming conventions have lost the majority of their original value. We now have color displays and syntax highlighting, so variables are distinguishable from methods by color in the IDE. I find it beneficial to use the same trick for something else, e.g. my code vs. framework code, or public API vs. internal implementation, or some other useful thing.

Comment: @Soonts _naming conventions have lost the majority of their original value_ you think? Read your own code in a few weeks' time and then we'll talk again about it - or even better - read someone else's code who has similar unconventional conventions as yours and doesn't care about naming - good luck debugging it ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t As a C++ developer, I do that almost every working day for the last couple of decades. Any non-trivial C++ project contains quite a lot of third-party code, typically with completely different naming conventions. With modern visual studio + visual assist, inconsistent naming conventions don’t cause any problems, as long as the naming is more or less OK.

Comment: @Soonts well, C# is not C++ and in C# there is a pretty strong well-defined commonly used naming guideline (exactly to avoid the _mess_ we have in other older and/or multi-paradigm languages). To follow a _custom_ guideline may be a problem when someone else outside your team (or a new one in your own team) has to deal with that code (we don't have _that many_ extension methods for CLR types, right?) Anyway, guidelines are just guidelines and they're not written in the stone then if your team has benefits breaking them then it's really your pick.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for another way to do this - using the .net framework (I have no experience with Linux, so don't hang me if it doesn't work there).

1)

```
public static bool IsNormal1(float v)
{
  return !float.IsInfinity(v) && !float.IsNaN(v) && Math.Abs(v) >= 1.175494351E-38;  
}
```

The magic number `1.175494351E-38` is discussed  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/system.single.epsilon(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

2) If you are willing to go `unsafe` you could do this:

```
const int floatExpMask = 0x7F800000;
public unsafe static bool IsNormal2(float f)
{
  return
    (*(int*)(&f) & 0x7FFFFFFF) < floatExpMask // Infinity and NaN
    && (*(int*)(&f) & floatExpMask) != 0; // Subnormal and zero
}
```

Comment: Epsilon and subnormal are different beasts (as already discussed in a now deleted answer). Second one should perform pretty well (with the exceptions I outlined in my answer, not everywhere integers and floating point have the same endianness)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I know. I were not trying to solve the endian problem, just to show a way to avoid the conversion via byte buffer, that was asked for :-)

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of .NET have [Double.IsNormal()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.isnormal):

> ```
> public static bool IsNormal(double d);
> ```
>
> Returns `true` if the value is normal; `false` otherwise.
>
> Applies to
>
> - .NET Core 3.1, 3.0, 2.2, 2.1
> - .NET Standard 2.1